# Remove blank line from awk output

Tags: bash, awk, diff

I am trying to remove leading whitespace from awk output. When I use this command, a leading whitespace is displayed.

```
diff  test1.txt test.txt | awk '{print $2}'

output: 

asdfasdf.txt
test.txt
weqtwqe.txt
```

How can I remove the leading whitespace using awk?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `awk '{print $2}'` shouldn't print any whitespace, if you haven't changed the field separator.

Comment: `awk '$2{print $2}'` may be ..... it is not clear what you want .... print if $2 exists ... `awk '$2!=""{print $2}'` better

Comment: do you mean the blank line at the top of your output? If so, please edit your question to indicate that (DON'T reply here). Good luck.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Ricardo Bustos M. That was exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help. That removed the leading whitespace from the output.

Comment: Hopefully by `That` you mean `awk '$2!=""{print $2}'` and not `awk '$2{print $2}'` as the latter will fail when `$2` contains a value that evaluates numerically to zero.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print the lines where $2 exists you can do it conditionally on number of fields

```
awk 'NF>1{print $2}'
```

will do.