# Output includes blank line for each condition that was checked using Awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a function that looks at every number in a file, checks if it is a perfect square, and if it is, increments a counter by 1.  The goal of the function is to count the total number of perfect squares.

```
awk 'function root(x)  
{if (sqrt(x) == int(sqrt(x))) count+=1 } 
{print root($1)}
END{print count}' numbers_1k.list
```

The output from this code gives a blank line for each time it checked the condition on a line of the file.  So if the file has 1000 lines, its 1000 blank lines in the output followed by the variable `count`

Is there anyway to avoid this?  I have checked previous similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789063/remove-blank-line-from-awk-output).

Comment: What is the expected output? You don't `return`anything from the function but yet you `print`. If you just want the count, remove the `print`.

Comment: Thank you.  which `print`?  I only want the count variable at the end.

Comment: Remove the `print` in `{print root($1)}`. That prints an empty line as the function `root` doesn't return anything and if it did return something, that would be printed.

Comment: it worked, thank you @JamesBrown

Comment: OK, I think I get this now.  So the `print` causes a line to be printed and isn't needed to actually run `root`.  Great explanation.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use `{ print root() }` where `root()` doesn't return anything, it should be:

```
awk 'function root() { return sqrt(x) == int(sqrt(x))}
     root($1) {count++}
     END {print count}' file
```

Btw, you don't need a function for that:

```
awk 'sqrt($1) == int(sqrt($1)) {count++} END {print count}' file
```

Comment: It's not out of scope. `count` needs to be defined like `function root(x,      count)` for that.

Comment: Was just about the check this. Yes, `awk 'function a() { count ++ } BEGIN{a(); print count}'` really prints `1`. I'm surprised. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @hek2mgl, `sqrt(x)` should be changed to `sqrt($1)` in 2nd solution sir.

Comment: @hek2mgl wrt your comment about being surprised. All awk variables are global except function arguments so if you want a local variable in a function then you just add it to the function arg list after the actual function args, by convention separated from the leading real args by a tab or multiple blank chars. `awk 'function foo(realarg, imlocal){imlocal=imglobal=realarg} BEGIN{foo(7); print imlocal, imglobal}'` would output `<null> 7` since within `foo()` the variable `imlocal` is a local variable to `foo()` while outside of it `imlocal` is a different, global variable of the same name.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for explaining that! Do you know the reasoning behind this behaviour? Was it the simplicity of implementation? I personally feel that this is a quite dangerous/cumbersome language behaviour.

Comment: I don't know but I could guess and my guess is it provides for brief, simple code. IMHO it's far less dangerous than a typo creating a new variable (e.g. `foo=7; print fooo`), which I trip over far more often than misunderstanding the scope of a variable, and the alternative to all variables being global unless declared in a function arg list would presumably be having to declare the scope of every global variable which is more cumbersome since they're far more common than local variables. You could solve all scope/typo mistakes by declaring all variables but that is C, not awk.

Comment: I guess it was easier implement then (and shows likely better performance). I just recently stumbled upon a bash application which makes highly use of _dynamic scoping_ which is more or less the same behaviour in the shell language. I found that very hard to understand and explosive to refactor.

Comment: In other languages you'd want a different decision but IMHO having all variables global unless declared local was the right decision for a small, focused text-processing language like awk. I personally would have preferred an explicit way of doing that rather than adding them to the function arg list but nbd and I understand why they did that since they had to create that local scope for the "real" function args anyway so I expect the implementation was practically free.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk 'function root(x)  
{if (sqrt(x) == int(sqrt(x)))
 {print x;count+=1
 } 
}
{root($1)}
END{print "count=",count}'  Input_file
```

Above code should add variable `count` whenever there is a TRUE condition found in function and you could increment its value inside function itself, finally you could print it in `END` block of `awk` code.

Comment: @hek2mgl, sure edited now, thanks for letting me know.